# Sound Design on Tribes: Ascend - Part 2

Tags: sound-design, foley, video-games

Hey Everyone,

Here are some updated gameplay videos from QuakeCon2011.  I would love any and all feedback that you guys have on my sound design for this game.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OlEJESgTEZE

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8w9XggeRD4

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Nj1J3YOfnw

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DnXAJN_jY0k

Thanks,

Benjie Freund

Comment: Great work! How long did it take to do all the sounds and music in Tribes?

Comment: Not so much that anything is wrong with this, but for two years it has gone 'un-answered' and the OP has since ignored it, so it keeps showing up at the top of the list all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine most people would look to someone of your standing for advice rather than vice versa.

The only criticism I can find is the world lacks what I could only describe as ambient sounds.  Simpler background sounds such as: distant gunfire or the wind rushing past you when you're travelling fast in an aircraft or the hoverbike.

I can't fault any of the implemented sounds at all, only the lack of small touches leave the map with a small sense of emptiness, audio-wise.

I hope that could help you!

Comment: Hey Jamal,

I am happy to say that there is 'rushing wind' and other map ambience.  The videos in this original post are a bit dated now as we have added and polished quite a bit.  :)  There are several new videos on youtube that demo everything.  Only trick is finding a video without some over bearing and loud music layered in.

On the same note, I have 5 Tribes: Ascend beta keys to give away!  If there is anyone here interested in getting a key just comment below.

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded and played a few rounds of it yesterday. I noticed and liked the rushing wind; it's really what creates the sense of speed when skiing. I wish it was more prominent though. Also, it sounded a bit flappy like there was cloth, which I thought confusing given the context (as far as I know my avatar's covered in metal :P ). I'll offer more critique as I play. Good job!

EDIT: Also, the sliding sounds are well designed and smoothly implemented. Me likey.

Answer (score 1):

I think the sounds itself really work well. For me the balance of the sounds is the only thing that bothered me sometimes (based on videos). Some really cool things like this sound when you respawn is very silent while some hit indicators are very loud. Those atmospheric stuff i would boos a little bit. Then the overall loudness is a bit more balanced.

Good Job!

Answer (score 0):

Must say very nice work man,

I think maybe the voice acting is a tad repetitive , and when the player skis through water I

think maybe add some water spraying or something, all gun SFX are great, good music levels

and hit points too, like when the player captures the flag etc.

any news on when tribes: ascend is released on PC? cant wait to play it, all the best with

this game =]

Answer (score 0):

sign me up matey, would love to play the Beta, if you have the keys to spare still, been looking forwards to this title for a while now,x

Comment: Here you go Grant.  visit www.hirezstudios.com to download the patcher.  YOUR KEY: M1C53002706AE84E90A0E4AF5  Enjoy!

Comment: ur a legend ur so nice to have done that, keep up the good work dude

Answer (score 0):

Excellent job! I've been playing a fair bit of tribes and the sound is perfect. How did you go about creating the laser gun sounds?

Comment: Thanks Dan!  I used GRM Tools for all my laser sounds..and probably 90% of tribes.  Sometimes I would program some hybrid patches for a good starting layer.

Answer (score 0):

I started working on the sound design for tribes november 2010, it is still an on going process.  not sure about the music, chris rickwood did that.